Возможно ли с помощь. pyrogram получать данные с reply клавиатуры?
Есть бот, и у него есть обычная клавиатура телеграм(не инлайн). Возможно ли с помощью pyrogram обработать текст на кнопках этой клавиатуры? Допустим отправлять какие-то сообщения в зависимости от содержания клавиатуры?
Привожу пример работы: Есть код, который отправляет боту сообщения, и со случайным шансом клавиатура из 4 кнопок меняется на другую, из двух. Так вот, можно ли при как-то обработать это изменение клавиатуры и прочитать какой текст появился на кнопках?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вот так получаете текст кнопки с номером button_n: message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0][button_n].text

@gord1402 Проблема в том, что мне нужна не inline-клавиатура

@Fufi Не заметил, тогда так message.reply_markup.keyboard[0][button_n]

При этом type(message.reply_markup) -> <class 'pyrogram.types.bots_and_keyboards.reply_keyboard_markup.ReplyKeyboardMarkup'>
